# Countdown flip effect without images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to to animate a countdown with a flip effect with only text, but I can't figure out how to do it,this is what I have thought:

- Each section of countdown (days, hours, minutes, seconds) has got 4 div

  - Upper current time
  - Lower current time
  - Upper next time
  - Lower next time

  @@@@@
  @ Upper @
  @@@@@
  @ Lower @
  @@@@@
- Then I thought to display only half number of each div

  - the upper with `fixed heights` and `overflow:hidden` on the parent
  - I have no idea to achive the same effect on the lower one
- To animate I thought to shrink each part (upper->lower) of the `class='active'` div and update the otherone
- I have also some problem on how to reset the shrinked div

Otherwise I thought to have always 4 divs in the same position and run 4 synced animations and 1 after, but I don't know if it possible to do and/or if them could cause some lag or flash" effect:

- First Layer: shrink the upper part, hide the lower part
- Second Layer(at the same time): hide the upper part
- Then shrink the lower section of the second layer
- Update(same `class='active'` way) and reset in some way

I hope that you will understand and could explain me which one is better and suggest me how to solve the "blank" points
**EDIT**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swYJ6/)

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with the initial state?

Comment: @joews I'm sorry, but at this moment I have only got a linear countdown, I preferred to have an idea on how to proceed before update the script, however if you need it I will do it

Comment: It will enable people to give you a better answer, even if it is just the non-animated html.

Comment: What do you mean with 'flip effect'? A jsFiddle would be nice indeed. You mean a timer countdown like http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/TN8Su/embedded/result,js,html,css/?

Comment: @KooiInc This is the effect that I would like to achive:  [flipclockjs](http://flipclockjs.com/) and this is what I have: [GitHub](https://github.com/Razorphyn/countdown.js).

Comment: However I'm writing a jsfiddle

Comment: @joews I have added the JSFiddle

Comment: Why not just download the plugin?